# Project-wide obfuscation with Google Closure

Tags: obfuscation, minify, google-closure-compiler

I'm using Google's closure compiler (set to compilation_level=ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS) to successfully minify/obfuscate my javascript code (I'm currently doing this semi-manually with a Sublime text plugin).

The vast majority of my javascript is in a single .js file, but of course if I obfuscate this code, and there's other snippets of javascript in my project's html files (perhaps referring to pre-obfuscation function names), then I'm going to run into problems.

What's the best approach to dealing with this dilemma?  Ideally I could run a whole project through the compiler which would recognise javascript inside html files and obfuscate them in a consistent way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export the functions that you need to call from HTML code, those will not be renamed (minified) by the compiler.  Either use the `@export` tag as part of the type definition, or call `goog.exportSymbol` or `goog.exportProperty` after they are defined. See the section in this wiki page about [@export](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler).

See the section *Solution: Export the Symbols You Want to Keep* on the page about [Advanced Compilation and Externs](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3) for discussion and yet another way:

```
function displayNoteTitle(note) {
  alert(note['myTitle']);
}
// Store the function in a global property referenced by a string:
window['displayNoteTitle'] = displayNoteTitle;
```

You can use obscure names for the things that are exported if you need to.  If you have a lot of code in the html files, move that code to functions in your single file and call those functions from html.  Closure Compiler will not compile code that is inside an html file.